# Listing Directory files with php

Tags: php, directory

I have a script which will list all the files from the image folder on the server into a drop down box.

```
$dir='images'; 

$list=scandir($dir);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) echo 'Selected: ' . $_POST['image'];

    foreach($list as $file)
    {
        //ignore . (current dir) and .. (parent dir)
        if($file!=='.'&&$file!=='..')
        {
            echo "<option value=\"$file\"";
           if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['image']==$file) echo 'selected="selected"';
            echo ">$file</option>";
        }
    }
```

What I am trying to do is when the file name of the image is selected that image is displayed.

```
 echo "<img src='images/". $file ."' />";
```

I tried using the file verable but it only seams to display the last image in the directory. How would I go about fixing this.

Comment: Do you mean that when the user changes the value, then submits the form, or do you mean instantly, with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean doing this on the form load, I’d say replace

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['image']==$file) echo 'selected="selected"';
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])&&$_POST['image']==$file)
{
    echo 'selected="selected"';
    $selected_file = $file;
}
```

then this instead

```
echo "<img src='images/". $selected_file ."' />";
```

Because at the moment, it’ll just load which ever one is last out of the `foreach`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do this with Javascript. Once the php script loads it has no one of knowing what is happening in the users window. You will want to create an event listener to the onChange even of your option group. And when the selection changes you will want to replace the src of the image tag being used to show a preview.

I'd highly suggest using a JS Library such as Jquery or simliar to help with the event listening, and dom manipulation.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/change/ the example shown is a good starting point and can easily be changed for your needs.